# Is there a short way to write indexOf above 100?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I have an object array with `id's` here I have the code where I refer to the id number 700:

```
if([700].indexOf(id) > -1) {
    $('.number-id').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'font-size' : '10px'});
}
```

Where id = `var id = locations[i][0].id;`

But I want to set this code `indexOf` to above 100 than execute the code. If I set the `if( id >= 100)` it executes the code for all of the classes `number-id`

here the html:

`var number = locations[i][0].id;`

```
 var marker_html = '<div class="rich-marker">'+'<span class="number-id">' + number + '</span>' + '</div>';

        var marker = new RichMarker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            flat: true,
            anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
            content: marker_html
        });
```

Where the output is:

```
 <div class='rich-marker'>
      <span class='number-id'>700</span>
</div>
```

This is what I am trying now:

```
  if( id >= 100 ){
                console.log(id);

                $('.rich-marker').find( function(){
                    $('.number-id').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'font-size' : '10px'});
                })
            }
```

It shows the Id's of all objects which are above 100 but it the font-size is not changing.

`This is the object array:

```
  var locations = [
    [{id: 1,  lat: 51.5239935252832,   lng:  5.137663903579778,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 2,  lat: 51.523853342911906, lng:  5.1377765563584035,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 3,  lat: 51.5237298485607,   lng:  5.137969675407476,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 4,  lat: 51.52355628836575,  lng:  5.138066234932012,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 5,  lat: 51.52340275379578,  lng:  5.138211074218816,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 6,  lat: 51.523199152806626, lng:  5.138382735595769,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 7,  lat: 51.5229955509073,   lng:  5.138511481628484,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 8,  lat: 51.52280529912936,  lng:  5.138543668136663,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 9,  lat: 51.523596340777075, lng:  5.138463201866216,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}],
    [{id: 700,lat: 51.523372714362736, lng:  5.1386992362595265,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'}]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `id >= 100`?

Comment: @Satpal No this does not work because it will set all `number-id` to font-size : 10px

Comment: You will want to post an example of the `HTML` also. I get the impression there is something important that is missing from your post that relates to the `.number-id`.

Comment: @imvain2 I added the html

Answer (score 0):

**one observation:**

jQuery `find` takes a `selector` or `element` as the `parameter`, you were passing a `function` that didn't return either. I assume you were really looking for something like this?

```
$('.rich-marker .number-id').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'font-size' : '10px'});
```

However, that still won't solve the problem of all `number-id`s being changed. This is where posting your overall markup is important because you aren't being specific enough as to which `.number-id` that you want to change, you are still saying change all '.number-id's that are `children` of 'rich-marker'.

Comment: It is like you said, how can i only speak to the marker with the id of 100+?

Comment: Why is this not working? `                    $(id).find('.rich-marker .number-id').css({ 'display' : 'block', 'font-size' : '10px'});
`